# simplexml rss unexpected ':'

Tags: php, rss, simplexml

I have this php (problem underneath)

```
<?php
$url = "http://woytest.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
if($rss){
echo '<h1>'.$rss->channel->title.'</h1>';
$items = $rss->channel->item;
foreach($items as $item){
$title = $item->title;
$link = $item->link;
$img = $item->media:thumbnail->attributes()->url; // error on this line
$description = $item->description;
echo 'Post Title: '.$title.'<br/>';
echo 'Post Link: '.$link.'<br/>';
echo 'Post thumbnail: '.$img.'<br/>';
echo '<br/><br/><br/>';
}
}
?>
```

the problem is the `media:thumbnail` with the colon which appears as `<media:thumbnail url='...'>` on the rss feed how can i overcome the problem i have tried `{'media:thumbnail'}` replacing just the `media:thumbnail` in the php but had no luck... I am new to php so could you please explain the error of my ways to.

Comment: I agree, indenting code for readability makes life too easy...

Comment: so much easier to find errors to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://alisothegeek.com/2011/07/picking-apart-xml-feeds-and-namespaces-with-php-and-simplexml/

Hopefully this should help you ;)

Example:

```
$entries = simplexml_load_file('http://woytest.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss');
$namespaces = $entries->getNamespaces(true);

foreach ($entries->channel->item as $feeditem) 
{
    $thumbnail = $feeditem->children($namespaces['media'])->thumbnail;
    $attr = $thumbnail->attributes();

    echo '<pre>';
    echo "URL = {$attr['url']}, width = {$attr['width']}, height = {$attr['height']}\n";
    echo print_r($attr, true);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: I am trying to apply it but i am having trouble... :/

Comment: Please see my revised answer to include an example. ;)

Answer (score 0):

call a **print_r()** to know about the object structure:

```
$url = "http://woytest.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($rss);
echo "</pre>";
```